# nginx dynamic HTTP/S resolves to https://_

Tags: nginx, https, vhosts

I'm trying to let all traffic for my nginx be redirected to HTTPS, independent of server name. So, any other vhost should be redirected to its HTTPS counterpart.

example.com -> https://example.com
test.com -> https://test.com
...

Yet, instead of using the incoming `$server_name` or `$host` (tried both), it keeps redirecting to a plain `https://_`. Is my config incorrect?

```
server {
  listen        80 default_server;
  listen        [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name   _;
  return        301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, rather silly. If you have previously setup any non-working configuration (e.g. one which will result in the faulty redirect), the browser will remember this redirect without asking the server again (as according to HTTP 301 - permanently moved). So, either clear the browser's data or try with a different one.

Comment: Just use 302 while testing until you 100% sure everything redirects as you want. Then check once more and replace 302 with 301.

Comment: rather silly but you saved me a few hours of head scratching, so take your +1

Comment: I lost half an hour banging my head against the wall, until i saw your answer. Thank you.